# Google Maps API v2 painfully slow when loading

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google Maps into my Android project.

I have a new activity that is launched from a menu on my home activity.

So far, the map activity creates the Google map and then centres it on my home city. But form tapping the menu item to showing the map, takes about 6-7 seconds to show the map, first showing a black screen for 2 seconds after tapping the menu item.

Once the map has loaded, it seems very slow to respond to touch input, lagging behind my finger as I move the map.

The device I am testing on is a Oneplus One, so the hardware is more then capable of the task.

Map code in activity (onCreate):

```
try {
        if(null == googleMap){
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapView)).getMap();

            //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LIVERPOOL, 12));

            if(null == googleMap) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException exception){
        Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
    }
```

So, what could the issue be? Is onCreate the right place to put the map creation? Is there anything option I can set to make it render faster?

Comment: How good is your internet connection?

Comment: @Emmanuel not terrible really - http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3951845473

Answer (score 1):

For a static position like in your example code it (the position) into the xml for the view.  Map should load from cache 2nd time you access it and it's very fast.